# Is boolean logic possible in django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, boolean

I want to do something like:

```
{% if ("view_video" in video_perms) OR purchase_override %}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: At some point, you should be using the model and the view functions for this.  Why isn't this a property of the model object?  Or a property of the logged-in user?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Django docs on boolean operators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators)

Gives you:

```
{% if user in users %}
  If users is a QuerySet, this will appear if user is an
  instance that belongs to the QuerySet.
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if a == b or c == d and e %}
```

Be aware that `and` has a higher order of precedence than `or`, and that parentheses are not possible. If required use nested blocks.

Comment: Well now. That would be the sensible place to look. I did try there, but on my phone and I couldn't find the bit I needed. Thank you for your help. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: +1 for the backhanded link comment at the end. Nicely played sir.

Comment: @will - It's probably worth noting that more complicated `if` constructs are only possible in Django 1.2 and later (see [the release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#new-in-1-2-smart-if))

Comment: @willcritchlow: "on my phone"?  You're using your phone to build a Django application?  Seriously?  You should consider buying a computer with a keyboard and a display, it might be easier than doing this on your phone.

Comment: Heh. I suspect he was just trying to find the docs on his phone while away from a computer. I do that sometimes. Inspiration hits, google a bit on the phone, bookmark anything useful.

Comment: Yeah - I'm not ninja enough to code on my phone (or even my laptop, it seems). I just tend to read around issues on the train. Thanks again for your help and I will look at the implications of the model / view options outlined by S. Lott above. One of my biggest issues with django is working out the "django" (or "pythony") way to do stuff.